# test styled-component using jest and enzyme class

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Says I have a component which has few div, so I can't do `expect(wrapper.contains(<div></div>)).toBeTruthy()`

Then, I have to get the class, like `expect(wrapper.find('myTargetedClass')).toBeTruthy(1)` but this only work with css-module and it won't work with **styled-component**, the class is hashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to find the exact `className` because the classNames are `hashed`. But you can check whether the component is having the `className` or not.

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { enzymeFind } from 'styled-components/test-utils';
const wrapper = mount(<StyledButton />); // StyledButton is your styled-components's component
const renderedComponent = enzymeFind(wrapper, StyledButton);
expect(renderedComponent.prop('className')).toBeDefined();
```

The above one will let you know whether the component produced by the styled-component is having the prop `className` or not.

Comment: I see, didn't know `styled-components` has test-utils, so this would be a common pattern to test react if we use styled-component? Does it work with shallow? why use mount here?

Comment: Yes. It does have the `test-utils`. I'm not sure whether it works with shallow or not. But the recommended way is using the mount. Here are more details https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#test-utilities

Comment: question, is finding the component having className make sense? shoudn't it be `.toHaveLength(1)` or `.exisits.tobeTruthy()` ?